# Can the alpha parameter of the ALS.trainImplicit() be greater than 1?

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, recommendation-engine

I have been testing the example code at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html#explicit-vs-implicit-feedback with my own data in place.

When I put alpha greater than 1, as is suggested by the source paper at

> http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=4781121

I get the error

> Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o629.trainImplicitALSModel.
>   Trace: py4j.Py4JException: Method trainImplicitALSModel([class
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD, class java.lang.Integer, class
>   java.lang.Integer, class java.lang.Double, class java.lang.Integer,
>   class java.lang.Integer, class java.lang.Boolean, null]) does not
>   exist

Is the limit for alpha in PySpark <1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PySpark doesn't enforce any limitations beyond these already enforced by Scala backend but the types matter. It means that:

```
ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, rank, numIterations, alpha=100.0)
```

is not the same as

```
ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, rank, numIterations, alpha=100)
```

with the latter one being invalid due to type mismatch. In other words types matter. Python `float` as a `java.lang.Double`, Python `int` is represented as a `java.lang.Integer`.